# Php - Group by similar words

Tags: php, regex, algorithm, keyword

I was just thinking that how could we group by or seperate similar words in PHP or MYSQL. For instance, like i have samsung Glaxy Ace, Is this possible to recognize **S120**, **S-120**, **s120**, **S-120**.

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is strip all non alphanumeric characters and spaces, and strtoupper() the string.

```
$new_string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $string);
$new_string = strtoupper($new_string);
```

Comment: And if you are keen of complicated algorithms, try [Damerau-Levenstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: @J0HN It is indeed a nice algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Only those? Easily.

```
/S-?120/i
```

But if you want to extend, you'll probably need to move from REGEX to something a little more sophisticated.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do here is to pick a format and standardise on it. So for your example, you would just store `S120`, and when you get a value from a user, strip all non-alphanumeric characters from it and convert it to upper case.

You can do this in PHP with this code:

```
$result = strtoupper(preg_replace('/(\W|_)+/', '', $userInput));
```